# Determining whether the sequence ${f_{n}}$ converges uniformly on the set $A.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Determining whether the sequence ${f_{n}}$ converges uniformly on the set $A$

\begin{equation*}
f_{n}(x) = g(nx),\quad g(x)=
\begin{cases}
x & \text{if }0 \leq x < 1/2,\\
1-x & \text{if } 1/2 \leq  x \leq 1,\\
0 & \text{if } x > 1.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

I know that the first step is to find the limit of $f_{n}(x),$ which I do not know how, could anyone help me in doing so?

Also the book did not wrote what is the set $A$, can I assume that it is $\mathbb{R}$ and start my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n(\frac 1 {2n})=g(\frac 1  2)=\frac 1 2$ for all $n$. This shows that (while $f_n\to 0$ pointwise) it does not tend to $0$ uniformly. It converges to $0$ uniformly on any set which is contained in $\mathbb R \setminus (0,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon >0$. Some details: it is clear that $f_n(x) \to 0$ for each $x$. If $f_n \to 0$ uniformly then, given $\epsilon >0$, there exists an integer $n_0$ such that $|f_n(x)-0| <\epsilon$ for all $x$ for all $n \geq n_0$. The main point here is the same  $n_0$ works for all $x$. Even if you make $x$ dependent on $x$ this inequality must hold as long as $n \geq n_0$.  To get a contradiction from this inequality you choose appropriate vales of  $x$ depending o $n$. This is what I have done.  [I get a contradiction when $\epsilon <\frac 1 2$].

Comment: what is the value of this $\epsilon$?

Comment: what is the intuition behind this solution?

Comment: what about considering the case $x = 1/3n$, will the solution remain the same? If so why?

Comment: How did you see that $f_{n} \rightarrow 0$ pointwise?

Comment: I can see  that the limit depends on the value of $x$ which invokes the definition of uniform continuity.

Comment: Could you provide more details please?

Comment: @hopefully See my answer now.

Comment: I have 2 questions related to your detailed answer: First- it is not clear for me why "$f_{n} (x) \rightarrow 0$ for each x" .... could you clarify this please?.......Second- what do you mean by saying in the fifth line "Even if you make x depends on x" could you clarify this please?

Comment: @hopefully If $x>0$ the $nx>1$ for $n$ sufficiently large. This implies $f_n(x)=0$ for $n$ sufficiently large, so $f_n(x)\to 0$.

Comment: Could you look at this question for me please  Kavi https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081891/a-difficulty-in-understanding-the-proof-of-dinis-theorem

Comment: and also when $x = 3/4n$ we can find a contradiction .....  am I correct? ..... I think $\epsilon \leq 1$ will also do what you  want Kavi .... am I correct?

Comment: @hopefully Yes, you are right.

Comment: your explanation is always wonderful Kavi :)