# A difficulty in understanding the proof of Dini`s theorem.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

The question and its answer is given below:

[image]
[image]

But I am not understanding the sequence of steps in the solution what are the ideas he using, for example:

1- In the second line why he is using a subsequence ${f_{n_{k}}}$ and he did not use only  apoint.

2-In the forth line why we are sure that there exists such $x_{k}$ for each $k$, and why we are doing this?

3-Also I see we arrived at a contradiction to that $f_{n}$ converges pointwisely to $f$,  is my understanding correct?

Could anyone clarify these discrepancies for me please?

Comment: For 1, write down the negation of uniform convergence. For 2, write down the definition of a supremum. For 3, yes.

Comment: For 1, why we are using a subsequence @Mindlack

Comment: Because it could happen that there is a subsequence that converges uniformly and another that does not. When you merge the two, the sequence converges pointwise but not uniformly. This won’t happen actually (which is basically inside the proof), but you don’t know that beforehand (write your definition).

Comment: and the subsequence may consists of only 1 element ....am I correct?@Mindlack

Comment: No, because uniform convergence for a sequence is an asymptotic property. You can modify any finite number of terms of the sequence and it does not change whether uniform convergence occurs.

Comment: I did not get your last comment @Mindlack

Comment: Uniform convergence is: $\forall \epsilon >0,\,\exists N>0,\,\forall k \geq N,\, \forall x,\, |f_k(x)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon$. So if you have just one term such that $|f_k(x)-f(x)| > \epsilon$ for some $x$, it does not violate the property... you just choose $N > k$.

Comment: I did not get your answer for number (2) , how writing the definition of the supremum will answer it ..... the supremum is greater than gamma does not mean that each element is greater than gamma ..... could you clarify this for me please? @Mindlack

Comment: You are right: the supremum being greater than $\gamma$ doea not mean that ebery element is greater than $\gamma$. It means that some element is greater than $\gamma$.